# В точной противоположности

Tags: пунктуация, морфология

Не будет ли кто-нибудь из присутствующих так любезен прокомментировать оборот "в точной противоположности"? Прежде всего, существует ли такой оборот, но не как сочетание предлога, прилагательного и существительного в косвенном падеже, а как член обслуживающего персонала? Т. е. не будет ли нарушением норм языка сказать: "Он поступил в точной противоположности ожидаемому" или "Название темы звучит из рук вон пафосно, в точной противоположности тому, что мне бы хотелось услышать"? Если не будет, то правильно ли я понимаю, что это производный предлог? И наконец, выделяются ли запятыми обороты, вводимые этим, с позволения сказать, предлогом?

Заранее благодарю-с. Если мои соображения далеки от здравого смысла, пусть это не оскорбляет ваших чувств: мне это свойственно :)).

Answer (score 2):

Есть предложное сочетание В ПРОТИВОПОЛОЖНОСТЬ.

Как  определить, когда перед нами предлог, а когда – другая часть речи?
Во-первых,функция предлога – связывать существительное, местоимение, числительное с другими словами в словосочетании и предложении. Во-вторых, предлог – это служебная часть речи, следовательно, мы не можем к нему задать вопрос. В-третьих, предлоги стоят либо перед существительным, либо перед определением, относящимся к этому существительному, если определение предшествует существительному.

Он поступил КАК?- в (точной) противоположности = точно противоположно=абсолютно противоположно. - наречие, т.к. является обстоятельством.
"Название темы звучит как?-из рук вон пафосно, как именно?-в точной противоположности тому,..." -обстоятельство, значит, не предлог и не оборот.Во втором случае обособляется как пояснение к первому  обстоятельству.
А вообще обособляются  обороты  (за исключением тех случаев, когда оборот входит в состав сказуемого или тесно связан с ним по смыслу)  с отглагольными предлогами включая, исключая, исходя из, начиная с, невзирая на, несмотря на, смотря по, судя по, а также ограничительно-выделительные обороты с предлогами вопреки, за исключением, кроме, независимо от, помимо. Или как пояснение

http://gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum_attach1

Answer (score 2):

В противоположность - это производный предлог со значением сравнения, употребляется только в форме В.п. Например: "В противоположность сухолюбивой и светолюбивой сосне, ель обычно растет во влажных низменных местах".

Высказывание "Он поступил в точной противоположности ожидаемому" мне не кажется правильным.Глагол "поступить" не может управлять П.п. существительного в подобных выражениях, поэтому существительное хорошо бы заменить наречием, например: "Он поступил прямо противоположно ожидаемому".

ОТВЕТ 2.Речь идет о неправильном управлении. Мы не говорим: "поступил в чем? о чем?", отвечая на вопрос "как он поступил?" Другие падежи (кого? и чего?)  также не подойдут. А вот В.п. здесь единственно хорош. Его основное значение - направленность, в данном случае он нам показывает направленность поступка. Можно сказать: "поступил так в нарушение всех правил" или "в противоположность ожидаемому". Выражение "в противоположность" - это как раз форма В.п. существительного, перешедшего в производный предлог.

ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ.Такой переход делается по смыслу: конкретное значение существительного ослабляется, его можно заменить другим существительным (например,  "в противовес"), также в значении предлога. В то же время формальные грамматические связи при переходе существительного в предлог сохраняются.

ОТВЕТ 3. В противоположность - это предлог, он основан на форме сущ. в В.п. И уже производный предлог управляет Р.п. существительного "сосна".

(В противоположность В.п.)сосне(Д.п.)

Comment: Прошу прощения, Вы хотите сказать, что сущ. "противоположность" не может иметь форму П. п.? Не то чтобы я не согласна с Вами, но просто такую же форму "противоположность" имеет еще в родительном и дательном падеже.

Comment: У Софии: "употребляется только в форме В.п. Например: "В противоположность сухолюбивой и светолюбивой сосне". Разве"сосне" - это винительный???